# sorting Hadoop results (similar to word count) by frequency

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to write a Hadoop map/reduce class that reads in a text file containing a list of actors and the movies they've played in (one movie per line) and returns the number of movies each actor has participated in.

Finally, I want the results to be sorted by the number of movies (either ascending or descending is fine). However, my code seems to sort the results by the number of characters in the movie title. I've tried everything I could think of, including reversing the output (Text, IntWritable to IntWritable, Text) and using a different comparator, but I could not get it to sort the results by the movie count.

I'm sure it's something extremely simple, but I could not figure it out for the life of me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

An excerpt from the data file:

```
Chan, Jackie (I)    The Forbidden Kingdom   2008
Chan, Jackie (I)    Kung Fu Panda 2 2011
Chan, Jackie (I)    Shanghai Noon   2000
Chan, Jackie (I)    Pik lik for 1995
Chan, Jackie (I)    The Karate Kid  2010
Chan, Jackie (I)    Shanghai Knights    2003
Chan, Jackie (I)    Around the World in 80 Days 2004
Chan, Jackie (I)    Rush Hour   1998
Chan, Jackie (I)    The Tuxedo  2002
Chan, Jackie (I)    Kung Fu Panda   2008
Chan, Jackie (I)    Rush Hour 2 2001
Chan, Jackie (I)    Rush Hour 3 2007
Davi, Robert    Licence to Kill 1989
Davi, Robert    Die Hard    1988
Davi, Robert    The Hot Chick   2002
Davi, Robert    The Goonies 1985
```

My code is below:

```
// MovieCountByActor.java

package ucsc.hadoop.homework2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
// import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import ucsc.hadoop.util.ConfigurationUtil;

public class MovieCountByActor extends Configured implements Tool {
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MovieCountByActor.class);

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Configuration conf = getConf();
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), MovieCountByActor.class);
        conf.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(CountSort.class);
        conf.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(CountSort.class);

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: moviecountbyactor <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        ConfigurationUtil.dumpConfigurations(conf, System.out);

        LOG.info("input: " + args[0] + " output: " + args[1]);

        Job job = new Job(conf, "movie count");
        job.setJarByClass(MovieCountByActor.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MovieTokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MovieCountReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setSortComparatorClass(CountSort.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        boolean result = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return (result) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MovieCountByActor(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    public static class MovieTokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
        private final static Text ACTOR = new Text();

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\\t");

            String actor = "";
            if (tokens.length == 3) {
                actor = tokens[0];
                ACTOR.set(actor);
                context.write(ACTOR, ONE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MovieCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text actor, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int movieCountPerActor = 0;
            for (IntWritable count : values) {
                movieCountPerActor += count.get();
            }
            result.set(movieCountPerActor);
            context.write(actor, result);
        }
    }

    public static class CountSort extends WritableComparator {
        protected CountSort() {
            super (IntWritable.class);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(byte[] b1, int j1, int k1, byte[] b2, int j2, int k2) {
            Integer a = ByteBuffer.wrap(b1, j1, k1).getInt();
            Integer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(b2, j2, k2).getInt();
            return a.compareTo(b) * -1;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing what `job.setSortComparatorClass(CountSort.class);` is doing - this is the comparator for your Key values prior to them being reduced. I think case you're just examining the Int part of the serialized Text object (the actor name), which explains why you're seeing your output in actor name length (and i imagine you'd see unexpected output if you have two actors the same name length that happened to hash to the same reduce instance.

To sort the output by the number of movies, you're going to need to perform another M/R job to take the output of your first job (movie counts by actor) and then use a mapper to switch the key / value (so the output key is the count, and the value is the actor name). Use a single reducer and you'll get the actor in ascending order of movie counts.

Comment: Either use a single reducer or use a custom range partitioner with multiple reducers if the data is huge.

Comment: @chris-white, any examples of how to use multiple M/R in sequence? I'm also interested into aggregating frequent values.

Comment: @feder - best to post a new question with some more detail

Comment: @ChrisWhite I did, can you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225091/how-to-sort-descending-from-the-30-most-frequent-words

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and @PraveenSripati 's comment is very useful, too!

Answer (score -2):

By default Map Reduce sorts the keys of output of reducer, So what you can do after counting the movies for a particular actor , you can set the output key of your reducer as moviecount and value as name of actor.

As follows:

```
public static class MovieCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable,Text> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text actor, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int movieCountPerActor = 0;
            for (IntWritable count : values) {
                movieCountPerActor += count.get();
            }
            result.set(movieCountPerActor);
            context.write(result, actor);
        }
}
```

Also, do following changes in the job configuration:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```